# Can't left click with USB Mouse on Firefox for Android in Tablet mode

Tags: tablet, firefox-for-android, mouse

I have a Rog Phone II (ZS660KL) & Desktop dock (ZS600KLD). When docked, the Rog phone asks the user to pick a display mode between:

- Mirror mode
- Twinview mode
- Tablet mode

Mirror mode is way too small (huge characters and icons) for an external screen. On both of the other modes, Android gets a second display; in Tablet mode, the second display is more adapted to a desktop-sized external monitor.

However, when using Firefox for Android (main or Nightly, versions 92 and 95), in both "Tablet mode" and "Twinview mode", my Logitech mouse (M-U00007) connected by USB to the ZS600KLD dock, cannot left click on any link or item inside Firefox. Clicking on a link with the physical left button results in an action similar to right click: a context menu appears to open the link in a new tab etc. Middle mouse button does the same "software right click" action. The physical right click does nothing. The back button works, but the forward button does not.

I also tried with an M185 that does not have the forward/back buttons, and the issue is the same. More interestingly, for both mice, the left click works in the address bar field, because it hands over to the Google keyboard. It's only where Firefox actually renders stuff that it does not work.

I currently do not see how to correct this bug, except switching to Chrome or using Mirror mode. This very specific issue does not happen in Chrome for Android or in Mirror mode.

Any idea how to solve this? For example, force a re-mapping of mouse events to specific actions?